# What is the generator of $\widetilde{H}_0(X)$, where $X$ is union of 2 segments?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have topological space $X$: union of two segments $\{ 1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. Obviously, $\widetilde{H}_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$. How do I find generator of $\widetilde{H}_0(X)?$
All I can see is that it must be coset corresponding to the chain $a\{1\}+b\{2\}+c\{3\}+d\{4\}$ with conditions $a+b\neq0,~c+d\neq 0$ and $a+b+c+d=0,$ but how do I find the exact form?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, looks like $[\{3\}-\{1\}]$ works as a generator, but still, is there a way to see that without computations? When the generator is found it's not hard to prove that it is a generator, bu in the case of a more complicated $X$ it might be difficult to actually find.

Comment: So, since $[\{3\}-\{1\}]$ is a generator, anything in the form $[\{point~ from ~one~ segment\}-\{point ~from ~another~ segment\}]$ is a generator too. Seems like a general principle. Can anyone give it some kind of a functorial explanation?

Comment: what's your definition of reduced homology here? I'm used to seeing it as relative homology $H(X,*)$, where $*$ is a chosen base point, in which case the generator would be one of the points in the other segment, or more generally, a degree one combination of the points in the other segment with any combination of points in the same segment as the base point.

Comment: @jgon Oh, actually, that might be exactly what I needed (I am reading a book and the generators it shows are really different from what I find).

I used the definition where we calculate homologies of augmented chain complex.

What do you mean by "degree one combination"? Does $[\{4\}-\{3\}]$ qualify as a generator? Does $[\{4\}]$?